# I want to make a user community (with posts that can be liked), what software do I need?

Tags: cms

I want to make a site that can carry out most of the functions that [the site descriptionari.com](http://www.descriptionari.com/) has:

- A front-end user registration system, complete with email validation, profile pages, etc.
- A feed system which lists the latest posts made by users.
- The main feature, which is that users should be able to post paragraphs that are displayed in the aforementioned feed system.
- A 'like' system.
- Users should be able to gain priveleges based on things they have done, and likes they have earned from the aforementioned 'like' system, eventually earning moderator privileges.
- The ability for users to "follow" other users.
- A notification system

Essentially, I want something like this:

[image: Mockup showing the 'feed': a list of paragraphs posted by different users, each with a number showing its likes]

I thought I would build it from scratch using HTML, CSS, PHP and SQL, but that didn't work so well, and it requires immense amounts of skill, which I don't have. I thought I could make it using WordPress considering that it requires no coding skill, but it turns out that only applies for blogging sites, and no plugin exists that can satisfy my needs (apparently).

**tl;dr**, I ask for three things:

1. What resources do I need to make a system such as the one above? What do I need to know?
2. The system I have proposed is vast. Which specific component do I begin with?
3. Can I even use WordPress to build such a site?

Comment: Well, you definitely need some form of Content Management System. Drupal is a perennial favourite, but I am not sure about the "likes" and badges.  You might google for a S.O clone. And the source of all knowledge for things CMS is at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

Comment: @Mawg I appreciate that, for the first time, someone has heard my plea. But please understand, I am very new to this world as a whole :/. I am a high school student with middling knowledge of a paltry number of programming languages. That said, what is an SO?

Comment: Sorry, that is Stack Overflow. The original site of Stack Exchange. So, if you you like the badges, upvotes, etc, of this site, google for a free clone of it.  With a good SCM, you shouldn't need to do any coding, unless you really want to. Go to CMS Matrix, select tham all & compare, then start checking "must have" features and whittle them down. If you can't find it there, you can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Googling shows these, plus many others - so, if you like this site,t hen go for one of these ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/open-source-php-clone-of-stackoverflow   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones  http://www.coordino.com/  http://digitizor.com/2010/12/01/stackoverflow-clone-php/

Comment: @Mawg Good stuff man. Thanks a lot, now I have a vague idea where to begin. I would upvote you if I could

Comment: Don't worry. None of what I posted is worthy of being called an answer, so I am happy to comment - without upvotes from you. We are here to help. Btw, it is allowed & even encouraged to answer your own question, so that others can benefit from the answer in future. So please come back when you have made a decision & post and accept your own answer. Good luck (btw, I once made my own community with Drupal, but found it to be very slow on shared hosting - and a dedicated server is expensive ...)

Comment: Reading your question, I assumed that a WordPress solution is not required (so I removed the [tag:wordpress] tag); but your last 3 questions aren’t that clear to me. Do you look for a software (i.e., a [tag:cms]) which allows you to create a website like you described, or do you look for WordPress plugins that allow you to build that website running on WordPress? And if there’s a CMS that can do this, does it have to be based on PHP (as you used the [tag:php] tag)? --- And please note that we can only recommend software/plugins here, no guides/resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/) , made for WordPress, may do most of those things for you. (I have not used this system)

Full Message Forums can do everything you want with add-ons or plug-ins.

[SimpleMachines](http://simplemachines.org/) is free and can do everything you want (with [Modifications](http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/)) I have used this system for years. It is easy to install and update.

[Invision Power Services](https://www.invisionpower.com/) Is a commercial (paid) system that will also do what you want.

With Themes, you can change the appearance of each of these systems.

Comment: while SMF seems to be the most attractive of the bunch, I just did a quick search about how to make it work with wordpress. The results were mostly negative, many users of certain forums hailed wordpress as a terrible, inefficient CMS with a bad user control system. I know none about this, so I'm asking you: Did you use SMF with wordpress yourself? And would you recommend it to a novice programmer, such as myself?

Comment: ^^^ I apologise for my question being largely opinion-based, as I'm aware how badly the community responds to such things >_> @kevan-sheridan

Comment: No, I do not use SMF with WordPress and would not recommend that approach for reasons similar to what you point out.  I think SMF is a great option for learning programming.  Modifications can be easily applied and you can always view the source files to see what changes are made.

Comment: I see. This is extremely valuable to me, thanks a lot!